# Erase in Adobe Sketch?

Tags: ios, adobe-photoshop

I'm using an iPad Pro with Apple Pencil... the Apple Pencil annoyingly doesn't have an eraser on the back end like the Pencil by 53. I've also not been able to locate a button that allows me to use the Apple Pencil as an eraser within the Adobe app. Any thoughts? Of course there's an undo button, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  The eraser tool is the last tool in the toolbar on the left.  It's the thin line with a blank spot in the middle.  Once someone tells you it seems pretty obvious, but it wasn't to me.

Comment: Well considering it looks nothing like the eraser in the desktop apps, it still isnt obvious lol